# CoinMarketCap API don't work on production server

Tags: php, coinmarketcap

I'm using the CoinMarketCap API to get the price of multiples crypto-currencies.

My PHP function is the following :

```
function updateCryptoPrice($conn, $Symbol)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=$Symbol&convert=USD",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip",
            "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: b38d4ec2-9a5e-4509-8381-0051dd83a6f2"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
    }

    $price = json_decode($response, true);
    $price = $price['data']["$Symbol"]['quote']['USD']['price'];

    echo $price;

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
    $lastupdate = date('d-m-y h:i');

    $sql = "
    UPDATE `CryptosPrices` SET `Price` = '$price', `LastUpdate` = '$lastupdate' 
                           WHERE Symbol='$Symbol'; ";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

It work perfectly on local, but when I upload it on my production server nothing work, I try to echo the $response but nothing happen and I have no error.

Do you think it come from Coinmarketcap ? My side ?

I've been on this problem for hours and can't figure out where is the problem (no error ..)

Thank you !

Comment: Is that your access key for the API?

Comment: Yes its an old key, I have re-generated another one since I published this

Comment: It works for me, I initially got a SSL error which I fixed by amending the `php.ini` to have an up to date `cacert.pem` Are you SURE you are not getting ANY errors. Remember a LIVE server will have error reporting set to LOG TO FILE ONLY!!

Comment: I'm actually using Hostinger and don't see any error log section (I'm contacting the support) but do you know how can I fix this SSL error on my server ? My SSL on my server is up to date and working

Comment: So add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) ___JUST while testing___ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`